# How do I make a hidden "div" visible on mouse hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm creating a dropdown menu that will contain the search engine form for a **fixed menu ba**r, that should display the search form when I hover the "search icon". The problem is that when I hover over it, it doesn't display the submenu and I don't think that it's even getting the "hover" events.

This is the effect I am trying to get
[image: This is the effect I am trying to get]

But even after adding the hover effect with visibility to visible, it remains like this
[image: But even after adding the hover effect with visibility to visible, it remains like this]

This is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="searchBar">
            <li>
                <img src="templateFiles/search.png">

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <form action="search.php" method="get" >
                            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Procure No Site" id="writeBox">
                            <input name="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="Procurar" id="button">
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
/*******Search Bar******/
.searchBar{
margin-top:30px;
float:right;
   /* display:inline;*/
}

.searchBar li, .searchBar img{
width:30px;
height:30px;
}

.searchBar li ul{
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
}

.searchBar li:hover .searchBar li ul{
visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: That selector `.searchBar li:hover .searchBar li ul` just doesn’t make any sense – you do not have another element with the class `searchBar` inside the `li` in the element with the class `searchBar`, and neither do you have an `ul` two `li`s deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target on the hover is looking for the div which you are already within again. You could add something to identify the form you wish to show such as a class of search and then target this, for example:

```css
/*******Search Bar******/
.searchBar{
margin-top:30px;
float:right;
   /* display:inline;*/
}

.searchBar li, .searchBar img{
width:30px;
height:30px;
}

.searchBar li ul{
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
}

.searchBar li:hover .search {
visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchBar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="templateFiles/search.png">
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <form action="search.php" method="get" class="search">
                      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Procure No Site" id="writeBox">
                      <input name="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="Procurar" id="button">
                  </form>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change This:

```
.searchBar li:hover .searchBar li ul{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

TO

```
.searchBar li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: ooops, that was the mistake. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @JoshBurgess I also found it. When you hover the image, if you move your cursor to the input of form. The form will be gone. But in this question, just about how to display the form.

Comment: @JoshBurgess and ToddMark, you are right, that's the other problem I just noticed that. well, this is embarassing -_- . But I'll solve it. Once more thank you very much for the help .

Answer (score 0):

First `<li>` is a list item and should be inside `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

and you have problem in the selector in css. `.searchBar li:hover .searchBar li ul` you add the `.searchBar` and its search for the second one inside the first one.

```
<div class="searchBar">
        <img src="templateFiles/search.png">

        <ul>
            <li>
                <form action="search.php" method="get" >
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Procure No Site" id="writeBox">
                    <input name="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="Procurar" id="button">
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

and css:

```
/*******Search Bar******/
.searchBar{
margin-top:30px;
float:right;
   /* display:inline;*/
}

.searchBar img{
width:30px;
height:30px;
}

.searchBar ul {
position:absolute;
display: none;
}

.searchBar:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where `.searchBar` shows up in your HTML. You need to correspond your `:hover` element to an element in the DOM that will receive the actual event.

Your HTML is invalid, and you're likely to be throwing it into quirks mode, which is going to lead to several unpredictable behaviors on your page.

Comment: There is no problem in `form` inside `li`

Comment: @Shibi You're right, of course. Brain fart from my .NET days.